# Workflow doesn't run on item update

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have two SharePoint 2010 workflows (created in SPD 2013) on a list. Let's call them W1 and W2. There is a field in list called "status" and its default value is 1.

W1 is set to run on item creation. It runs and updates value of "status" to 2. At this stage W2 is supposed to run (because it is set to run on item changed) but it doesn't until I manually edit the item and just press "Save" at which W2 runs.

Strange thing is W2 is working fine on Development server (i.e. it automatically runs when W1 changes "status" value to 2) but not on Production.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you check who the 'Modified By' is for the list item after the W1 is run.  If it is System Account then workflow (W2) will not get started automatically by the system account.

Comment: So if that's the case shall I publish workflow again using different account OR is there a way to change workflow user account through powershell or GUI?
Will it affect already running workflows?

Comment: You would need to re run the workflows. Also, are the field values updated through Impersonation Step?